# Error on circleci deployment on pspell debian

Tags: docker, ubuntu, circleci, pspell

Well I get this error on CircleCI:
checking for PSPELL support... yes, shared
configure: error: Cannot find pspell

when I run this step: - run: `sudo docker-php-ext-install pspell`
I check online and find the solución but only for yum
`yum install aspell-devel`
How I make this done with apt?

Comment: Circleci config.yml version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.4-node-browsers-legacy
    working_directory: xxxx
    steps:
      - checkout
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "xxxx"
      - run: sudo docker-php-ext-install pspell
      - run: sudo composer self-update
      - run: git clone xxxx
      - run: cd xxxx
      - run: composer install

Answer (score 1):

I think the package is just named differently under apt.  Try `apt install libaspell-dev` ?  (got the name from `apt search aspell`)

Comment: Please specify what exactly isn't working, like your error message.

Comment: error es show below is: **checking for PSPELL support... yes, shared configure: error: Cannot find pspell** ,  when you run build in circleci